# Why is session state lost so quickly?

Tags: asp.net, iis, session-state

We have a web application through which customers access information. It has been reported by many customers that they are logged out within 5 minutes of no activity. I believe this should only occur after the default 20 minute idle timeout, and this is the case when accessing the web app from inside our domain.

I also spent a few days troubleshooting an error in which some of the user's session data was lost between post backs about 60% of the time, causing an application error since the next page needed the data. The only resolution was a work-around in which I use an additional mechanism for caching the data between postbacks and pull the data from that cache if the session data is gone.

I have also noted that some websites that *I* visit which require logon credentials will also kick *me* out between postbacks. For example, a website for a school I take classes at requires logon credentials to their portal. At home I never have any issue, but if I access it from my work domain I often get random errors indicating that my credentials have been lost (i.e. "Unauthorized access is not permitted" after logging in and browsing to a page).

Combing the web for ideas has led me down a few paths, but most address the IIS worker process and ASP.NET and have not helped me.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions about how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you post the section of your web.config where the session parameters are set? Do you manipulate the session settings in the code at all?

Comment: Session parameters are not being set in web.config. No manipulation of session settings in code.

Answer (score 0):

this is not because of the programming problem...this is because of your host capacity...as you know session are a type of memory that is create for each user when they access to your website and it's terminated when they finish visiting...so in this case I suppose the number of site visitors has risen up,so by default when the memory become full, it kicks one session out and causes all these problems...I think the best thing to do is calling where you get your host services and ask for a service that cover sites needs

Comment: We host the site, there are relatively few concurrent users, and the web server memory usage is way below threshold.

Answer (score -1):

You just store your session value in to cookie so you can access that value when session terminate.. or you can use global file to manage session state..

Comment: This does not address the question.

Comment: @field_b you had written -> I believe this should only occur after the default 20 minute idle timeout, and this is the case when accessing the web app from inside our domain. I also spent a few days troubleshooting an error in which some of the user's session data was lost between post backs about 60% of the time....

Comment: @field_b your credentials are getting null because your session value is getting null. that's why u are logging out..